# whenever I try install a new software i get a newaliases: fatal: myorigin parameter setting must not contain multiple values:

Tags: dpkg, postfix

Running newaliases:

```
newaliases: fatal: myorigin parameter setting must not contain multiple values: nduduzo-Inspiron-5559 nduduzontshangase@gmail.com
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 75
Setting up python3-pyrsistent:amd64 (0.15.5-1build1) ...
Setting up python3-websocket (0.53.0-2ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3-wsdump to provide /usr/bin/wsdump (wsdump) in auto mode
Setting up python3-dockerpty (0.4.1-2) ...
Setting up python3-importlib-metadata (1.5.0-1) ...
Setting up python3-docker (4.1.0-1) ...
Setting up python3-jsonschema (3.2.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up docker-compose (1.25.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I was trying to setup mail and I did not think that it would cause such an error.

now I want to know how to I clear and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `postfix` installation is corrupted for one or another reason. There seem to be some error is the configuration files (`/etc/postfix/main.cf` and `/etc/init.d/postfix`). I'd recommend purging it and reinstalling it. It will re-create all the configuration files.

Run the following command to purge it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg -P postfix
```

Now run a force install:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Now, there will be no errors in installing any package or software.

---

If you want postfix back, you can reinstall it using:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install postfix
```

If you're getting errors after reinstalling it, you can remove it's post-installation script. It's a well-known issue and removing the post-installation script is the only solution found so far:

```
sudo apt update
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.postinst
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This will fix the error message.

Comment: I was trying to set up mail, but I did not complete the setup. Then I tried installing Docker and I got this error in the end

Comment: Thank you, its fixed

Comment: @nduduzontshangase Awesome! Glad it's working as expected. You can accept my answer by clicking the tick mark button near the votes. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very clear. "myorigin parameter setting must not contain multiple values". Look into your Postfix configuration file (usually this is `/etc/postfix/main.cf`) and check the value of `myorigin` parameter (this value is even quoted in the error message: `nduduzo-Inspiron-5559 nduduzontshangase@gmail.com` - these are two values separated with space, which is not allowed). Fix it. `myorigin` is the default domain name Postfix will add to sender and/or recipient email addresses, if they consist of an username only, without domain. This value should not be an email address (so `nduduzontshangase@gmail.com` is wrong) and should be a FQDN (so `nduduzo-Inspiron-5559` is wrong as well). Put there a domain name that you want your emails to go out with as the sender.